# Select all of the items that are owned by current user, show less items if they're not

Tags: mysql, select

Imagine you've got 3 tables: users, songs, and users_songs. Users are editors of their own songs or songs they've been invited to edit but they can't edit anyone elses.

```
users
-id
-username

songs
-id
-is_ready
-name

users_songs
-id
-user_id
-song_id
```

`is_ready` is either 0 or 1 - it means that the song is not ready/ready to be displayed in a listing on the front page.

I want to select ALL the songs that are owned by the current user id, whether ready=1 or ready=0, but only select the songs that are **ready=1** if they're owned by other user ids.

I think I might be asking for conflicting joins so I'm not sure if it's possible..

Comment: How do you know if the user has been invited to edit the song. It's not clear from the structure.

Comment: Their ID would be in users_songs.

Comment: If so, I think Alma Do Mundo's answer is the one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be like (`$user_id` is current user id):

```
SELECT
  songs.*
FROM
  songs
    LEFT JOIN users_songs ON songs.id=users_songs.song_id
WHERE
  user_songs.user_id=$user_id
  OR
  is_ready=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT songs.*
FROM songs, users, users_songs
WHERE users.id = users_songs.user_id 
AND (users_songs.song_id = songs.id OR songs.is_ready = 1)
AND users.id = [current user id]
```

Try and let us know if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one query.

[See example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aca5/13)

```
SELECT us.user_id, s.name, s.is_ready
FROM songs s, users u, users_songs us
WHERE us.song_id = s.id
and 
(u.id = us.user_id 
OR (us.user_id <> u.id AND s.is_ready = true))
AND u.id = 1;
```